# Check if the argument passed but does not exist

Tags: r

In my function, I would like to determine the existence of variable passed as argument, for example:

```
test <- function(input) {
  out="nothing";
  if (exists(input)) {out="input exists";} else {out="input does not exist";}
  return(out);
}

myvar=0;

test(myvar);     # I expect "input exists"
test(blablabla); # I expect "input does not exist"
```

Is there any way to implement such behavior?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is one way

```
test <- function(input) {
    varname <- deparse(substitute(input))
    out="nothing";
    if (exists(varname)) {out="input exists";} else {out="input does not exist";}
    return(out);
}
```

Here use use the `deparse/substitute` combo to turn the parameter value into a string. Then we can use the standard `exists()` to see if a variable with that name exists. And I get

```
> test(myvar);     # I expect "input exists"
[1] "input exists"
> test(blablabla); # I expect "input does not exist"
[1] "input does not exist"
```

Comment: great, thanks a lot! I would never arrive myself to this unobvious solution.

Comment: Hi i m new to R. Indeed whats the difference between as.character(input) and the deparse(substitute()) one? Thanks

Comment: as.character() simply coerces the value of the input variable to a character. substitute() actually takes the parameter that was passed to input and turns it into an expression (basically and frozen piece of code) without ever looking at it's value. Then `deparse()` takes that expression and turns it into a character vector. So if `myvar=0` and is passed to `test()`, `as.character(input)=="0"` and `deparse(substitute(input))=="input"`

Comment: Hello again @MrFlick, I would be grateful if you could also take a look on updated question: I've realized that the solution with `deparse(substitute())` doesn't work so easily in case of call from another function...

Comment: @VasilyA You should not update old posts with new questions. If you have a new issue, you should start a new question.