# Check if the passed argument exists

Tags: r, arguments

I am trying to check if a variable passed as argument to a function exists. Based on the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23923046/check-if-the-argument-passed-but-does-not-exist) question I have the following:

```
myfunction <- function(x) {
  stopifnot(exists(deparse(substitute(x))))
}
```

However, it does not work if the argument is an expression to be evaluated:

```
a=c(1:10)
myfunction(a+10)
```

How can I make sure that I capture non-existent variables if the argument is not just a variable?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @hadley I would like my function to handle situations when the argument does not evaluate to an existing object. For example `myfunction(get(ls()[3]))` may or may not pass an object. Thank you for your input.

Comment: And why do you want to do that?

Comment: I would like my function to do different things depending on whether  argument exists or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is combining `match.call` (returns the call to the function) and `all.vars` (returns the names in an expression). Try this:

```
fcn <- function(x) {
  varnames <- all.vars(match.call())
  for (x in varnames)
    stopifnot(exists(x))
}

fcn(a) # returns error, as expected
#Error: exists(x) is not TRUE

# create "a"
a <- 2
fcn(a + 1) # no error returned since "a" exists
```

Similarly,

```
fcn(a + b) # error returned since "b" does not exist
#Error: exists(x) is not TRUE
b <- 4
fcn(a + b) # no error since "b" now exists
```

Comment: Thank you for your nice solution. This indeed works fine when the variable a or b appears in the call. But it does not capture the non-existent b when called like this: `fcn(get("b"))`.

Comment: This new case that you raise suggests me another approach. What about simply trying to evaluate the expression passed as argument? 
`fcn <- function(x) tmp <- try(eval(match.call()[[2]]))`, this will naturally return an error if any of the variables involved in it are missing.

Comment: Yes, this seems to be what I am looking for. Thank you.

Comment: @javlacalle no need for all the eval stuff, just try to evaluate the argument directly `fnc <- function(x) tmp <- try(x)`